# Spinner false not reflect on template

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I am using a material spinner as a loader when calling the HTTP request. It's working fine if using a single component. If used in other components problem goes like this...

```
rechargeSpinner2 = false;


fetchElectricityBillData(providerId, customerId){
    const customer_id = customerId; 
    const provider_id = providerId; 
    if(provider_id == 'undefined' || provider_id == null || provider_id == ''){
      this.toastr.error("Please Select Provider.");
      return false;
    }
    if(customer_id == undefined || customer_id == null || customer_id == ''){
      this.toastr.error("Please Enter Customer ID");
      return false;
    }
    **this.rechargeSpinner2 = true;**
    this.rechrageService.fetchElectricityBill(customer_id, provider_id).subscribe(Response =>{
      console.log(Response.data);
      this.electricityBillData = Response.data;
      this.openDialogForBill();
      **this.rechargeSpinner2 = false;**
      console.log(this.rechargeSpinner2);
    })
  }
```

Variable change in ts file but its not change in the template, but when I click anywhere its changed.
What is the problem goes here?

Thanks in advance.

Templete file(html file)

```html
<mat-tab>
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <img src="assets/images/icon/electricity.png" alt="Smiley face" height="30" width="30">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <b> Electricity Bill</b>
      </ng-template>

      <mat-card>
        <div class="box1">
          <form action="">
            <p>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width:100%">
                <mat-label>Electricity Provider</mat-label>
                <mat-select matNativeControl placeholder="Select Electricity Provider" id="providerId" #electricityOperator>
                  <mat-option value="SelectDefault" disabled="disabled">Select Electricity Provider</mat-option>
                  <ng-container *ngFor="let provider of serviceProviderData">
                    <ng-container *ngIf="provider.service_id == 5">
                      <mat-option style="width:3000px; font-size: 9px;" value="{{provider.id}}">{{provider.provider_name}}</mat-option>
                    </ng-container>
                  </ng-container>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
            </p>
            <p>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width:100%">
                <mat-label>Customer ID</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Enter Customer ID" id="customerId" #electricitNumber>
              </mat-form-field>
            </p>
            <div class="spinnerstyle2" *ngIf="rechargeSpinner2 == true">
              <mat-spinner color="accent" diameter="28"></mat-spinner>
            </div>
            <p>
              <button mat-flat-button color="primary" style="width:100%" (click)="fetchElectricityBillData(electricityOperator.value, electricitNumber.value)">Fetch
                Bill</button>
            </p>
            <p>
              <mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width:100%">
                <mat-label>Amount</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Enter Amount" #electricityAmount>
              </mat-form-field>
            </p>
            <p>
              <button mat-flat-button color="primary" style="width:100%" (click)="recharge([electricitNumber.value, electricityAmount.value, electricityOperator.value, electricityOperator.triggerValue, 'Electricity'])">Pay Electricity Bill</button>
              <span *ngIf="progressbar">
                <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" color="warn"></mat-progress-bar>
              </span>
            </p>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="assets/images/recharge/banners4.jpg" class="box2" style="height: 477px;">
        </div>
      </mat-card>
      <br><br>
    </mat-tab>**strong text**
```

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 1. Where is your template? 2. You'll need to elaborate on '*If used in other components problem goes like this...*'

Comment: If the UI only updates when you click it the cause is probably that change detection is not running when the variable changes. You may be able to fix this by injecting the ApplicationRef into your service and then calling `this.appRef.tick();` after you've changed the state of `this.spinner`, but a better solution would be to fix whatever the source problem is, but we'd need more information for that.

Answer (score 0):

Change Detection strategy solves this problem.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Inject, ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, ViewRef } from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { RechargeService } from 'src/app/services/recharge/recharge.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';


export interface DialogData {
animal: string;
name: string;
}
@Component({
selector: 'app-recharge',
templateUrl: './recharge.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./recharge.component.css'],
**changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush**
})
export class RechargeComponent implements OnInit {
rechargeSpinner = false;
rechargeSpinner2 = false;
progressbar:boolean = false;

**constructor(private toastr: ToastrService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef){ }**


ngOnInit() {
  **if (!(this.ref as ViewRef).destroyed) {
      setInterval(() => {
        // this.ref.detectChanges();
        this.ref.markForCheck();
      }, 100)
  }**
}
}
```